# Is $f(z)=e^{z^2+z+1}+e^{Im(z)}$ Holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$$z=x+iy$$
I can write the function $f$ in this form:
$$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
 
$$e^{x^2-y^2+2ixy+x+iy+1}+e^y$$

$$v(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2+2ixy+x+iy+1}$$
$$u(x,y)=e^y$$

I need to check these conditions:

\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{cases}

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0 \ne (-2y+2ix+i) \ \ e^{x^2-y^2+2ixy+x+iy+1}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

$f$ is not holomorphic

Is it correct? 
Thanks!

Comment: You choose wrong $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Note that since $e^{z^2+z+1}$ is holomorphic, $f(z)$ is holomorphic if and only if $e^{Im(z)}$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis in the OP is not correct.  While it is true that

$$f(z)=e^{z^2+z+1}+e^y=e^{(x^2-y^2+x+1)+i(2xy+y)}+e^y$$

the real part of $f(z)$, $u(x,y)$, is given by

$$u(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2+x+1}\cos(2xy+y)+e^y$$

and the imaginary party of $f(z)$, v(x,y)$ is given by

$$v(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2+x+1}\sin(2xy+y)$$

---

> An easy way to proceed to test analyticity is to note that $e^{\text{Im}(z)}=e^{-i(z-\bar z)/2}$ and
>
> $$\frac{\partial e^{-i(z-\bar z)/2}}{\partial \bar z}\ne 0 \tag 1$$
>
> which is equivalent to showing that the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Independence_of_the_complex_conjugate) are not satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f(z) = e^{z^2+z+1} + e^y$ is holomorphic in some open connected set $U\subset \mathbb C.$ Because $e^{z^2+z+1}$ is holomorphic in $U,$ we then have $e^y = f(z) - e^{z^2+z+1}$ holomorphic in $U.$ But every real-valued holomorphic function in $U$ is constant (from the C-R equations or the open mapping theorem). Cleary $e^y$ is not constant on $U,$ contradiction.

Comment: (+1) The open mapping theorem is a very nice touch, well done.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct, the real and imaginary parts of $f$ ($u$ and $v$) are not given correctly:
\begin{align}
f(x,y)& =\exp\left[(x+iy)^2+x+iy+1 \right] +\exp(y) \\
&=\exp\left[ (x^2-y^2+x+1)+i(2xy+y) \right]+\exp(y) \\
&=\exp\left[x^2-y^2+x+1\right]\left(\cos(2xy+y)+i\sin(2xy+y)\right)+\exp(y) \\
&=\left[\exp(x^2-y^2+x+1)\cos(2xy+y)+\exp(y) \right]+i\left[\exp(x^2-y^2+x+1)\sin(2xy+y)\right].
\end{align}
From here, $u$ and $v$ are clear.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to notice that $e^{1+z+z^2}$ is holomorphic while $g(z)=\exp\text{Im}(z)$ is not, since the integral of $g(z)$ on the boundary of the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, counter-clockwise oriented, is not zero.

Comment: Plenty of holomorphic functions are bounded and nonconstant on that strip.

Comment: @zhw.: my bad. Argument fixed.